# Giving labels to local variables with GDB

Tags: disassembly, gdb

In the GDB debugger of Linux, is it possible to give a local variable (at specific offset from the %esp register) a constant name, which I will see everytime I call **disassemble** instead of seeing the address?

I mean something like the capability of IDA Pro to set names to unknown variables.

Comment: Use IDA to attach to a remote GDB instance? This combines the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Reflection: `gdb` is not really meant for that, I mean reverse-engineering tasks. It is really intended to be a debugger. You may combine it with a reverse-engineering tool (as suggested by 0xC0000022L.